# Duplicates when filtering by group with Mondrian

Tags: pentaho, mondrian, star-schema

I'm trying to create a Mondrian schema to be used in Saiku. The rest of the schema is working correctly, but the main filter isn't.
I have tried several ways on making this work, but so far I always get duplicates.

This issue can be duplicated with only two tables we'll call `fact_table` and `user_group`. The `fact_table` contains the user id and measures such as:

```
user_id|amount
1      |10
2      |15
3      |17
```

The `user_group` table contains the `user_id` and the group(s) it belongs to. If a user belongs to several groups, it will have several rows

```
user_id|group_id
1      |100
1      |200
2      |100
```

Every time I run a query for the groups 100 and 200 I get the following incorrect data:

```
user_id|amount
1      |20
2      |15
```

Note that the amount for user 1 is duplicated because it belongs to two groups. The problem is that a dimension is not expecting to have duplicates by the id. Is there any way to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

It seems your data warehouse schema does not follow [star schema](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_schema) rules. Your *dimension table* `user_group` should contain only one *key* column with *unique* values (the `user_id` column is insufficient).

More possible solutions come to play:

**1) Adding `group_id` column to `fact_table` (leads to duplicate amount records).**

*Fact table:*

```
user_id | group_id | amount
1       | 100      | 10
1       | 200      | 10
2       | 100      | 15
3       | #null    | 17
```

**2) Consider `fact_table` and `user_group` tables as dimensions and a new fact table on the top of them.**

*Fact table:*

```
new_fact_key | user_id | group_id 
1            | 1       | 100      
2            | 1       | 200      
3            | 2       | 100      
4            | 3       | #null
```

*1st Dimension table:*

```
user_id|amount
1      |10
2      |15
3      |17
```

*2nd Dimension table:*

```
group_id
100
200
100
```

You can replace `#null` values by surrogate keys. I recommend to read this book about data warehouse modelling [The Data Warehouse Toolkit, 3rd Edition](http://www.kimballgroup.com/data-warehouse-business-intelligence-resources/books/data-warehouse-dw-toolkit/) to find out more about star-schema concepts and surrogate keys.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I still have to make some tests to make sure it works. But there should be some other way that does not involve moving dimension data to a fact table.